# Unable to delete columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame (df2) with 2 levels: subject and time and 5 variables.
as i want to merge it with another dataframe (df1) that has exactly the same structure same id, same years (but in the original dataframe id and time are integers)

normally you would just delete the first two rows with

```
a<-df2[,-c(1,2)] 

df1<-cbind(df1,a)
```

but as they are factor levels R somehow does not let me delete them. I tried to set them to a.numeric but that didn't work either. What am I missing?

Here is the structure of my df2:

```
> str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2262 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ id          : Factor w/ 87 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ time        : Factor w/ 26 levels "1987","1988",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ shares      : num  NA 0.016 0.016 0.016 0.016 0.016 0.016 0.16 0.16 0.159 ...
 $ tacc        : num  NA 38.7 31 50.5 28.7 ...
```

I would like to remove the entire columns id and time

Comment: `df2[,-c(1,2)]` removes the first two columns. Are you perhaps looking for `droplevels`? Your question would be clearer with an example.

Comment: I just want to delete both columns with the factor variables in it. Library(plm) data(grunfeld) for example looks similar to my data

Comment: "looks similar to my data" is not really the same as providing a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are trying to describe. Also, your question text needs to be edited.

Comment: I'm really confused on why data[,-c(1,2)] is not working. Is this some kind of safety function or I don't see any other reason why this is not working

Comment: You will easier get an answer if you have a small `data.frame` (use `dput` to show it to us) and how the result should look like. What you are using is a `data.table`, so you have to use `df2[, -c(1,2), with=FALSE]`

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I was not aware of the different syntax of data.table

Comment: To anyone who may happen to land on this page: the Q&A are now obsolete; see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit 2020-04-16

`data.table` has evolved since this original Q&A -- simple queries in `j` like `1:2` and `'V1'` are treated as they would be in `data.frame` -- as column selection criteria.

Hence `DT[ , -c(1, 2)]` now would return the same if `DT` is a `data.table` or a `data.frame`. Leaving the below for posterity:

---

The problem seems to be that you are actually trying to use `data.frame` syntax on a `data.table`.

Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:2, time = 3:4, shares = 5:6, tacc = 7:8)
DT[, -c(1, 2)]
# [1] -1 -2
DT[, -c(1, 2), with = FALSE]
#    shares tacc
# 1:      5    7
# 2:      6    8

DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
DF[, -c(1, 2)]
#   shares tacc
# 1      5    7
# 2      6    8
```

Note that it's not best practice to use index positions like this, if only because it makes the code a little more obscure in the long run.